# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript not working on ASP Button click event

Tags: asp.net, alert, scriptmanager, registerstartupscript

***what I have tried***

I'm trying this since yesterday, **to trigger a alert() when an ASP Button_Click**. However, when I paste this script in Page_Load it works perfectly fine.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('Fill all fields.');", true);
```

I have also tried it with below code, `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` which works on page load and not on ASP Button_Click

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('Fill all fields.');", true);
```

---

***what I need to do***

Need to validate the textboxes present in client side, if these textboxes are empty it should display a alert dialog.

Comment: are you using update panel?

Comment: no i'm not using update panel..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('Fill all fields.');", true);

return;
```

Comment: Doesn't do a thing for me. Why would returning from an already-returning void method do anything?