# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() method not working - ASP.NET, C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, scriptmanager

I have used `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()` method in order to show an alert when particular thing happens in back end.It works fine in page load method but not in particular method which is called when a specific button is clicked . I Couldn't find a solution because in another page it works fine in both page load and the method.

**Script Manager RegisterStartupScript Method**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('msg');", true);
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="PostBackController"/>
<button class="some-class" id="btnSave" runat="server" onclick="btnSave_clientClick();">SAVE</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function btnSave_clientClick() {

     // code

     if (some_condition) {

        $('#PostBackController').val("btn_save");
        __doPostBack();

     }
}
```

**Page Load Method**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PostBackController.Value == "btn_save")
    {
        uploadDocSave_ServerClick();
    }
}
```

**Method Wish should be called when button Clicked**

```
protected void uploadDocSave_ServerClick()
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('msg');", true);
}
```

Comment: add breackpoint on `uploadDocSave_ServerClick()` and check if its getting called or not?

Comment: I already did. of course, it is getting called.

Comment: try wrting a `return;` statement after the line.. it seems there are other codes being executed after the script is registered

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Look at that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484407/scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-not-working-on-asp-button-click-event) please. I hope it helps you.

Comment: It didn't resolve my problem.I think there is somethig else wrong here. Thanks for the response Orkun and DT

Answer (score 5):

My deepest condolences for OP if you still have to work with Webforms. This is how you can solve it in a minimal way while reducing traffic:

Codebehind sample:

```
public partial class About : Page, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Unless the button is serverside clicking it will reload the page
        // registering the page like this prevents a page reload.
        var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
        scriptManager?.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Page);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        var javascriptCode = $"alert('server method called and triggered client again. {DateTime.Now.ToString("s")}');";

        // if your key isn't changed this script will only execute once
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(udpMain, typeof(UpdatePanel), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), javascriptCode, true);

        // updating the updatepanel will inject your script without reloading anything else
        udpMain.Update();
    }
}
```

Webforms sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clientFunction(sender, args) {

        alert('client function called');

        <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Page, "callServerFunction") %>

        args.preventDefault();
    }
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="udpMain">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
        <h3>Your application description page.</h3>
        <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
        <button onclick="clientFunction(); return false;">raise server function</button>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

If you Used Update Panels Then You can Use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascriptFunction();", true);
```

Other Wise You can Use

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
        (GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascriptFunction();",true);
```

Comment: Yes I use firebug. but there is no error in console or anywhere. This is weird.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Client side:

```
Use Literal Control
<asp:Literal ID="IMsg" runat="server" Text=""/>
```

Server side:

```
string msg = "<script>alert('Change successfully');</script>";
IMsg.Text = msg;
```

I think it will help you. It works fine in my projects.

Comment: Why did you post that as an image?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove line containing:

```
__doPostBack();
```

in the JavaScript code.

Comment: Run the app in Firefox with Firebug Console On - to see if there are any errors reported. There maybe some JavaScript code from outside blocking execution of your alert function.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am late at the party. Use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558(v=vs.110).aspx) of `RegisterStartupScript` method, and set the first parameter the button on which you want to click to register the javascript function. Like:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnSave, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('msg');", true);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

***THE REALLY SIMPLE WAY***

You can wire up a `<button runat="server"></button>` to a server event using the `onserverclick` attribute:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="some-class" id="btnSave" onserverclick="uploadDocSave_ServerClick" runat="server">SAVE</button>
```

**C# Handler:**

```
protected void uploadDocSave_ServerClick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('msg');", true);
}
```

---

***WITH CLIENT SIDE VALIDATION***

If you want to add some sort of JavaScript check before postback, you can do that from the `onclick` attribute:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="some-class" id="btnSave" onclick="return btnSave_clientClick();" onserverclick="uploadDocSave_ServerClick" runat="server">SAVE</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function btnSave_clientClick() {

     // code

     if (some_condition) {

        return true; // allows the control to do a postback

     }
}
```

**C# Handler:**

```
protected void uploadDocSave_ServerClick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('msg');", true);
}
```